# Android Studio Chipmunk : Gradle Sync issues

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-chipmunk

I recently upgraded to Android studio Chipmunk, now I created a new project and this Gradle project sync failed every time. I tried updating Api in SDK manager, and also deleted the .gradle and .idea files. Invalidate and restart but nothing works.

```
    Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Comment: Your gradle cache mght be corrupted delete it and re run

Comment: @JunaidKhalid plz can you explain how to do that or at least give me some link from where I can do that. As I have seen many youtube videos on that but nothing works for me. Also, I tried creating a new project it runs very fine with no Gradle issues but the project I'm working on, is still having Gradle build issues.

Comment: there is a .gradle folder in your project directory, delete it

Comment: @JunaidKhalid No, I tried this but it's not working

Comment: try clean and rebuilding project

Comment: Chipmunk Patch 1 now available.. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/05/android-studio-chipmunk-202121-patch-1.html?m=1